# how to run nunit test standalone

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a bunch of .net nunit tests that need to be run on specific machine.

Unfortunately I have only remote desktop access to this machine and unable to install visual studio and all stuff.

Question: is there a way to run unit tests as standalone application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Just use the [NUnit Runner](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.4) that is supplied with NUnit.